# Google Assistant and Dialogflow in German

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I created a Google Assistant app like the "Silly Name Maker" from the tutorial.

But as default language, I chose German. I named it "Spitzname".
When I go to the Simulator page to test my app "Spitzname", I can not invoke the app.

When I trigger: "Mit meiner Test-App sprechen" (Same like "Talk with my test app" in German), I get as a response "Hallo" (same as Hello) or "Ich grüße dich" but NOT the WELCOME-message I coded. (I did delete all these standard welcome messages)

I coded in the Welcome-INTENT some "User says" sentences to start the app with these sentences. But even then I use exactly the same sentences, I get an error:

> Sorry, this action is not available in simulation.

It looks to me as some standard code ("Hallo" welcome indicates it) is executed, but not my hand written code. Does anyone has an idea?

The English tutorial version works fine.

Here comes the debug output:

```
{
  "agentToAssistantDebug": {
    "agentToAssistantJson": {
      "conversationToken": "[]",
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "expectedInputs": [
        {
          "inputPrompt": {
            "richInitialPrompt": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "simpleResponse": {
                    "textToSpeech": "Hallo!"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "possibleIntents": [
            {
              "intent": "assistant.intent.action.TEXT"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "responseMetadata": {
        "status": {},
        "queryMatchInfo": {
          "queryMatched": true,
          "intent": "73fd8852-77fd-4199-bcf0-7dd4337cfbfe"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "assistantToAgentDebug": {
    "assistantToAgentJson": {
      "user": {
        "userId": "ABwppHHaBma7a2MnJ3VTkiOFruguuPJdgJ0q89UpM5vGiiu_cpfzqMGLHIFLCLWmLzDWASivNH6RoTOK82ihgy2PieI",
        "locale": "de-DE",
        "lastSeen": "2018-01-03T15:12:10Z",
        "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}"
      },
      "conversation": {
        "conversationId": "1514992981116",
        "type": "NEW"
      },
      "inputs": [
        {
          "intent": "actions.intent.MAIN",
          "rawInputs": [
            {
              "inputType": "VOICE",
              "query": "Mit meiner Test-App sprechen"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "surface": {
        "capabilities": [
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
          },
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
          }
        ]
      },
      "isInSandbox": true,
      "availableSurfaces": [
        {
          "capabilities": [
            {
              "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
            },
            {
              "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "curlCommand": "curl -v 'https://api.api.ai/api/integrations/google?token=a65b4c9aeb7646d295e19697de9f9593' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Google-Actions-API-Version: 2' -H 'Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjFkYjAxNzVkMWM1ZjQ1YTlkZGEyNzlmYzkxYjY3YTEzOGJjMjA1NTUifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJzaWxseW5hbWVtYWtlci01YmI5ZiIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYWNjb3VudHMuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbSIsImp0aSI6IjNjM2U5N2I2ODYzNGM5OTZiZmYxZWUwMDMwZDkyZmUwMWQ2NTZkNGYiLCJpYXQiOjE1MTQ5OTI5ODEsImV4cCI6MTUxNDk5MzEwMSwibmJmIjoxNTE0OTkyNjgxfQ.XVAMf1B11-KF0OGFGXvq45UOM2CURSshl7GR8B188NCwII_zpJnY9lGJjRE315_j1tSX9IeiTXFGLUQic93IMtAg1VHHyINcuEBdIqRSh4oiZ_7iIiFfZCDDE0AObMQE3r90d3dW4mkaSJ7YoKaXJBL5SpRs_8BVbGkIHMKD5lYmq1MC02HkxH2bLoGYTRthx-Jjpt0jVCFxYfBG1Z-lj3unEwWyufk3D8arlwLdDfeRafQdkLScF2WUaN9rcPDtIViwzOFWGcKOt4W30w27zwe-PMopJA1vEtKY0mA-pxgj1Aqx-40Tn6qx-dQPTdmd4Te6939OGI-fbW8kfHEVxQ'  -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Cloud-Functions/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)' -X POST -d '{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"ABwppHHaBma7a2MnJ3VTkiOFruguuPJdgJ0q89UpM5vGiiu_cpfzqMGLHIFLCLWmLzDWASivNH6RoTOK82ihgy2PieI\",\"locale\":\"de-DE\",\"lastSeen\":\"2018-01-03T15:12:10Z\",\"userStorage\":\"{\\\"data\\\":{}}\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"1514992981116\",\"type\":\"NEW\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.MAIN\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"VOICE\",\"query\":\"Mit meiner Test-App sprechen\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"}]}]}'"
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you include screen shots that include the Debug tab from the simulator? You said you named the action - did you add this name to the Action Console configuration in the German language configuration? (And can you provide screen shots from the Action Console configuration?)

Comment: Hm, now I added a third action - a trivia game from a template. But when I invoke the Simulator test it does not invoke the trivia game but the English dialogflow action?! I see clearly in the menu the name of the trivia game but when I type "Talk to my test app" the dialogflow action is triggered...

Comment: You can only have one action at a time in test - the simulator works with the one that is being tested, which isn't always the one that is showing. Make sure you're looking at the right one by redeploying it to test.

Comment: I do not understand. Does the URL not indicate the software which is in test? When I see https://console.actions.google.com/project/demoproject-db762/simulator I would expect to test demoproject. When I see https://console.actions.google.com/project/spitzname-db538/simulator I would expect to test spitzname. Is this wrong? For trivia game I just clicked "TEST" and the simulator page opened. But still with wrong content. How do I explicit redeploy a certain action to the simulator area?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had to fill out the app information complete and to give unique names for the different apps. Now it works.